# Nginx Ingress: doesn't run services and get 503 service unavailable

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to create an ingress file to route urls into the inside services. but after calling in postman, it just returns 503 error.
this is my ingress file config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
spec:
  rules:
   - host: posts.com
     http:
       paths:
         - path: /posts/create
           pathType: Prefix
           backend:
             service:
             name: posts-clusterip-srv
             port: 
              number: 7000
```

this is my posts deployment file and cluster ip:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: posts-depl
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: posts
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: posts
   spec:
     containers:
        - name: posts
          image: 4765/posts
---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
     name: posts-clusterip-srv
 spec:
    selector:
       app: posts
    ports:
      - name: posts
        protocol: TCP
        port: 7000
        targetPort: 7000
```

when in postman I send this request `http://posts.com/posts/create` just returns `503 service unavailable`. I try to curl the cluster Ip `curl http://posts-clusterip-srv:7000` but it responses  `Could not resolve host: posts-clusterip-srv`

I don't know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Does your app server accept request on /?
As path: `/posts/create` will forward the request to your server which will receive a request on /.
Concerning the `curl http://posts-clusterip-srv:7000` it depends of the set up of your cluster:

- If you are using a local cluster on your computer you should modify your `/etc/hosts` add your local IP as `posts.com` then you should be able to curl it.
- If your cluster is on a server it seems that it is a DNS problem, same way as above you can add the server IP to your hosts file to avoid using the DNS.